# Is there a way to tell a FileProvider filesystem to keep certain files local?

Tags: icloud, filesystem

I'm using a filesystem which is hosted on a cloud provider and is made available on macOS via the [FileProvider API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider). While it seems to be the same framework that Apple's iCloud Drive uses, it doesn't seem that the 3rd party filesystem I'm using keeps files sticking around with the same rules that the Finder does with iCloud.

In other words, I have files from iCloud which seem to never get offloaded to iCloud (i.e. they DO get sync'd to the cloud, but don't turn into one of those "click the cloud icon to download" type files). I haven't done anything to those iCloud files to make them stick around. On the other hand, with this 3rd party service I clicked the 'cloud download' button and things were good, but by the afternoon the file was already offloaded to the cloud.

Is there a way through like a plist or prefs config to influence how aggressive a FileProvider solution does its offloading, or is that purely in the code of the 3rd party implementer of the framework?

Comment: What cloud provider? How full is your disk?

Comment: Cloud provider shouldn't matter, but as far as the disk "fullness" I am high single digits.. but we're talking files that are a total of a few dozen MB at best that it is expiring.   Really more just hoping there is  some OS level way to influence the behavior rather than going to the people who maintain the provider software.